# Class template with variadic constructor; storing parameters into std::vector< std::shared_ptr<> >

Tags: c++, templates, constructor, shared-ptr, variadic-functions

I'm trying to design a class template where its constructor has a variadic constructor and each parameter type must be the same data type. I would then like to store all parameters into a `std::vector< std::shared_ptr<T> >` container. If no parameters are passed in then the very first `shared_ptr<>` in the `vector<>` will be set and stored as a `nullptr`. Also I would like to be able to keep track of how many parameters are passed in. So far this is what I have tried.

**declaration**

```
template<typename T>
class Nodes {
private:
    unsigned m_numParams;
    std::vector<sstd::shared_ptr<T>> m_vNodes;

public:
    explicit Nodes( T... );  // Not sure how to set first parameter as being default to nullptr along with the variadic syntax.

};
```

**definition**

```
template<typename T>
Nodes<T>::Nodes( T... ) {

    if ( /* no parameters passed in or 1st parameter is nullptr */ ) {
        T* ptr = nullptr;
        m_vNodes.push_back( ptr );
    } else {
        for each ( /* parameter with same data type */ ) {
            std::shared_ptr<T> sptr( new T() );
            m_vNodes.push_back( sptr );
        }
    }
    m_numParams = m_vNodes.size();
}
```

My understanding of basic templates is decent, but my use of variadic functions or templates are limited and I'm trying to learn new methods to further improve my overall skill set within the c++ language. I would like to know if my initial approach is logically the correct path; if this concept is possible to achieve and if so, what would be the most efficient way to implement this so when I use this class template this is what I would be expecting to and to actually have happen as in this example case below:

```
#include "SomeHeader.h"

int main() {

    int x = 3;
    int y = 5;
    int z = 7;

    Nodes<int> someNodes( x, y, z );

    return 0;
}
```

The internal nodes private member variable would have `shared_ptr<int>` where

```
Nodes::m_vNodes[0] = address of x with value 3 stored
Nodes::m_vNodes[1] = address of y with value 5 stored
Nodes::m_vNodes[2] = address of z with value 7 stored
```

and if no parameters are passed as in...

```
#include "SomeHeader.h"

int main() {

    Nodes<int> someNodes();

    return 0;
}
```

the internal member variable would have a ''nullptr` stored in the vector[0] location. Would I need to also implement its default constructor Nodes(); Or is this achievable all from a single constructor?

Once I have this constructor properly working then I would have no problem moving forward to write the functions or methods to add, remove, retrieve, store, arrange or sort the data, compare the data, or manipulate the data. I've been searching here and there and haven't seem to find anything relevant to what I'm looking for. Any tips, advice, help, links or examples would be truly appreciated and I kindly thank you in advance.

Comment: It sounds like you might want a [`std::initializer_list`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/initializer_list)

Comment: @NathanOliver I did upvote your comment as I like and appreciate the suggest or tip. However I was trying to see how this could be done in the manner in which I originally asked. I'm trying my hand at learning variadic functions / variadic templates etc.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`initializer_list` seems a better choice, but with variadic template, it should be something like:

```
template<typename T>
class Nodes {
private:
    unsigned m_numParams;
    std::vector<std::shared_ptr<T>> m_vNodes;

public:
    Nodes() : m_numParams(0), m_vNodes{nullptr} {}

    template <typename ... Ts>
    explicit Nodes( Ts&&...ts) :
        m_numParams(sizeof...(Ts)),
        m_vNodes{std::make_shared<T>(std::forward<Ts>(ts))...}
    {}
};
```

with `initializer_list`:

```
explicit Nodes(std::initializer_list<T> ini) :
    m_numParams(ini.size())
{
    for (auto&& e : ini) {
        m_vNodes.push_back(std::make_shared<T>(e));
    }
}
```

[Demo](https://ideone.com/2HsCmN)

Comment: Thank you for the timely answer; it is working appropriately. The syntax is new to me, and I haven't yet used make_shared<>( forward<>() ) so this is a great help, not in just getting this to work but helping to understand how to write variadic fuctions / templates. This is nice and clean and compact. The reason I want this structure as opposed to the initializer list is that I have use for these members being stored as a shared pointer in a vector. Now if this can be done in the other approach with the std::initializer_list; then I'm open for alternatives as well.

Comment: When I try to use the `std::initialize_list` version of the constructor in my miain.cpp file where I am passing the integer variables x,y,z into the constructor of nodes, it does not compile for me; I'm not sure how to use this version in my application; would you be able to show me an example?

Comment: After doing some trial and error in my main.cpp I finally got the `std::initializer_list` version to work. I had to create an instance of it as such: `std::initializer_list<int> ini{ x, y, z};` and pass that into the `Nodes` constructor.

Comment: @FrancisCugler: I added a demo link for `std::initializer_list`.

Comment: Thank you; but I was able to figure it out after some time and trial and errors. I'll still take a look at the link you provided.